# Pattern for batching and bulk processing

Tags: design-patterns, batching

I've data queried from the db that looks a lot like the following

```
Job Site    File    List
-------------------------------
1   SiteA   file2.txt   2
2   SiteB   file2.txt   2
3   SiteA   file23.txt  23
4   SiteC   file2.txt   2
5   SiteB   file12.txt  12
6   SiteA   file29.txt  29
7   SiteB   file28.txt  28
```

I am supposed to initiate instances for each site (sites A, B & C), and then do processing with, i.e., for eg, for siteA, work on file2.txt, file23.txt & file29.txt. This "processing" can happen in some order, but it has to be one after the other (not simultaneous).

So my 1st task is the collate the sites - and create instances for each. How do I do this?

PS: I figured for the processing part I should use some sort of an iterator pattern...I prefer solutions in any modern complier language...like c#, vb, c++, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have understood what you want to achieve, but I think that what you need to do is:

1. Get the distinct values of `Site` from your data
2. For each of the values obtained in the previous step
   2.1. Instantiate the site
   2.2. Get all the associated values of `File` and process each one

In C# using LINQ, it would be something like this:

```
var siteNames=data.Select(d => d.Site).Distinct();
foreach(var siteName in siteNames) {
    var site=new Site(siteName); //Or use a factory method, a sites list, etc
    var files=data.Where(d => d.Site==site).Select(d => d.File);
    foreach(var file in Files) {
        site.ProcessFile(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot use any sort of loop...which was y I figured out the iterator pattern is best that job...can u also show a non-linq version of the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

I would have a visitor object with a hash table which iterated over each entry.

For each entry:
- if it didn't exist in the hash table, the visitor object would instantiate a site for it.
- the object would then get the file and process it.

This would have the advantage that you would do the grouping and processing in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

I endorse the idea of a worker for each site.

One additional problem - application state.

When your app starts does it care what happened before? Consider an application crash when a few of the files have been processed. On restart presumably the app will process the files again? Is that a problem?